# datepicker onmouseenter message for disabled dates

Tags: jquery, events, datepicker, mouseenter

Trying to get some information to the user about disabledDays in datepicker. I want to ideally have a small box show over date when hovered to give info. If that's not possible something like this would do, but I haven't been able to get the event to stop on mouseout. More than that though this piece of code places the text on the outer periphery of the datepicker in the greyed out areas before the 1st and after last date of month.

```
<p class="pickdate">
<label for="pickDate"/>
<input type="text" class="pickDate"/></p>

$(function() {
$("#pickDate").datepicker();
$(".ui-state-disabled").live("mouseover", function() {
$("pickdate").text($(this).text('n/a'));
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to bind the `mouseout` event as well?

```
$(".ui-state-disabled").on('mouseout', function() {
  $("pickdate").hide()
  //or whoever you want to hide it
}
```

Debugging:
If nothing is happening insert some log messages:

```
$(".ui-state-disabled").on('mouseout', function() {
  console.log("mouseout event fired! YEHA!");
  //or alert("mouseout event fired! YEHA");
  $("pickdate").hide()
  //or whoever you want to hide it
}
```

If the message appears probably `hide()` will not working on your pickdate. Though strange I don't know how exactly meant to hide it. Feel free to perform any other tricks instead of the given code.

Should the log message or alert not appear at all probably the mouseout event is fired. You can test this behaviour by binding it to an empty test div. Just to be free from any disturbances. Check if your browser is supporting this element type.

Also which version of jQuery are you using? I see you performed `live()` which as of version 1.7 is deprecated and replaced by `on()`.

(Before this edit I also mistakenly used `bind()` instead of `on()`. Even worse. So maybe just try the corrected code one more time.)

Comment: still seems to not disappear on mouseout.

Comment: Updated with some debugging tips. Also notice my mistake by using bind() instead of on(). Just try it one more time. Big sorry!

Comment: Yoshi, on doesn't work for some reason. I'm using 1.8.13. live works but it puts the text on hover in areas where I don't want it(the outer part of the calendar) that is disabled by default. Thanks again

Comment: if it's coming down to positioning I may suggest you a follow up question and recommend you to provide a screen shot as well. It's hard to picture it for me but I'm sure other people are better in this than me :)